# Strange behaviour of parameterized SQLite query

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, parameterized-query

*(Feel free to improve the question title if you can think of something better.)*

**Question**: Consider the following SQLite query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS value UNION SELECT 2 AS value)
 WHERE value <= ?
```

When I use `1` as the parameter, I *expect* the query to yield `1`, yet it yields `2`. Why does this happen?

---

**Additional information**:

This is a minimal working example to reproduce the issue (Android):

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) " +
        "  FROM (SELECT 1 AS value UNION SELECT 2 AS value) " +
        " WHERE value <= ? ",
        new String[] {String.valueOf(1)});

c.moveToFirst();
Log.i("", "Result: " + String.valueOf(c.getInt(0)));
```

It *might* have to do with the fact that the parameter is passed as a string, but, alas, there is no other way to pass parameters to the SQLite API, so I guess I'm not doing anything "wrong" here and it's SQLite's job to convert the value appropriately. I've also observed the following when using a non-parameterized version of the query (this might or might not be relevant for the issue):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS value UNION SELECT 2 AS value)
 WHERE value <= 1              -- yields 1

SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS value UNION SELECT 2 AS value)
 WHERE value <= '1'            -- yields 2
```

Comment: may be you can use SELECT '1' and SELECT '2'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's said in the `rawQuery` documentation:

> [...] You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. **The values will be bound as Strings.**

And, quoting the [SQLite doc](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparisons):

> The results of a comparison depend on the storage classes of the
>   operands, according to the following rules [...]
>
> - An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value.

As both 1 and 2 *are* integers, they're both less than '1' (TEXT value). That's why this statement:

```
SELECT 2 <= '1'
```

... returns 1 in SQLite.

You should probably use ...

```
WHERE value <= CAST('1' AS INTEGER)
```

... instead. Or you can use the fact that all mathematical operators cast both operands to the NUMERIC storage class with `WHERE value <= + ?`, but this is less clean, imo.

Note that in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE _id < ?
```

... [the value of `?` will get its affinity adjusted to the affinity of `_id` *column*](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#expraff) - hence they will be compared as numbers, if `_id` is NUMERIC.

Comment: That's it, thank you! So automatic type adjustment of the parameters only works when comparing them *directly* to a database column... that's good to know.